# Check merge for conflicts using GitPython

Tags: python, gitpython

I am performing a merge using GitPython:

```
repo.merge_tree(branch1, branch2)
```

After the merge, I would like to see whether or not there were any merge conflicts. How do I do so?

Comment: I already found an answer to this question, but I had a hard time finding the answer myself. [So I'm posting the question and answer that I would have found helpful](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 8):

*Nota buena:* I wasn't quite able to get this answer to work when I tried it in my own project. I'm not sure if it's because the information I present in this answer is incorrect, or if it's because there was another issue in my code.

At any rate, the information in this answer is difficult to find, and I believe it is either correct or very close to correct, so it is still useful. Just be aware that there be dragons when you use this advice.

---

After the merge, GitPython stores the state of the working directory in `repo.index`. `repo.index` includes a method, `index.unmerged_blobs`, that lets you check the status of every blob (file) that has been modified but not staged for commit. **You can iterate over these blobs to see if any have merge conflicts.**

Each blob is associated with a status from 0 to 3 (inclusive). Blobs with status 0 were merged successfully. Blobs with status 1, 2, or 3 have conflicts after your merge.

---

To be precise, the `index.unmerged_blobs` function returns a dictionary of filepaths to a list of tuples. Each tuple contains a stage from 0 to 3 and a blob. Here's how that breaks down:

- Each key in the dictionary is a path to one of the files in your project.
- Each value is effectively a list of blobs that modifies the file referenced by the key. This is because, in the general case, it's possible to have multiple changes staged that affect the same file.

  - Each entry in the list stored by the value is a tuple.

    - The first entry in the tuple is the stage of the blob. Immediately after a merge, a stage of 0 means that the blob has no merge conflicts. A stage of 1 to 3 means that there were conflicts.
    - The second entry in the tuple is the blob itself. You can, if you choose, analyze it to see changes at the blob's original contents. For the purpose stated in the question, you can ignore the blobs.

Here's some code that ties it all together:

```
# We'll use this as a flag to determine whether we found any files with conflicts
found_a_conflict = False

# This gets the dictionary discussed above 
unmerged_blobs = repo.index.unmerged_blobs()

# We're really interested in the stage each blob is associated with.
# So we'll iterate through all of the paths and the entries in each value
# list, but we won't do anything with most of the values.
for path in unmerged_blobs:
  list_of_blobs = unmerged_blobs[path]
  for (stage, blob) in list_of_blobs:
    # Now we can check each stage to see whether there were any conflicts
    if stage != 0:
      found_a_conflict = true
```

Comment: I got the bulk of this answer from this cached Google Groups discussion: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:WNqVZWPhBvAJ:https://groups.google.com/d/topic/git-python/SefBpTUNXVY+&cd=8&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: And the API reference for GitPython: https://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html#git.index.base.IndexFile.unmerged_blobs

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function for this, like this:

```
import os
import git

def git_conflicts(set_repo=os.getcwd()):
    # Get the ".git" repository using the set_repo parameter or if nothing is 
    # checked, check the current folder.
    repo = git.Repo(set_repo)

    # Check the status of the ".git" repository and move to a list.
    status_git = repo.git.status(porcelain=True).split()

    # Checks if "UU" which means conflict, is in the "status_git" list, if it 
    # has the function "conflicts" it returns True, otherwise False
    if "UU" in status_git:
        return True

    return False
```