# Python - how to check whether the path is under a git repo? and extract the repo name

Tags: gitpython

I'm trying to develop a Gatekeeping script in python `rollin.py` with the following requirements:

1. Assume user would launch the `rollin.py` script from anywhere within his local git cloned area to push his commits to the master repo
2. Now, `rollin.py` script would

   - clone a repo from master
   - pull user commits and merges into the cloned repo
   - Run the compliance tests
   - If passes, then push those changes to master repo else discard and notify the user

Now within `rolloin.py` script, how would I check the the repo name and user's git clone path? (since user can launch the `rolloin.py` script from anywhere in his local area)

Is there any existing function or method available? otherwise I'm thinking to implement reverse recursive search from `cwd` to locate the .git and and then url from it's config file.

Answer (score 9):

#### Using the [GitPython](https://pypi.org/project/GitPython/) library

You can achieve this with the already authored GitPython module.
[Read the docs](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#meet-the-repo-type).

```py
$ pip install GitPython
```

Python snippet to print the base git path and the `origin` remote url.

```py
import git
    
# Raises InvalidGitRepositoryError when not in a repo
repo = git.Repo(".", search_parent_directories=True) 
print "Location "+ repo.working_tree_dir
print "Remote: " + repo.remote("origin").url
```

To create a new git repo

```py
import git 
    
newRepo = git.Repo.init("my-git-repo", mkdir=True)
```

Comment: thanks for highlighting the parameter `search_parent_directories`!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `os.system` to run `git rev-parse --git-dir`, which will return the path to the `.git` folder of the repository in which the command is run. For more info, see [How to find the path of the local git repository when I am possibly in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293944/how-to-find-the-path-of-the-local-git-repository-when-i-am-possibly-in-a-subdire)

Comment: Thanks @Ari Lotter. the above pointer helped me and it worked. Now, I'm trying to find out for merge conflicts in the merged repo, I found there's a post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030400/check-merge-for-conflicts-using-gitpython Is there any better solution apart from this?